# Is there a defect in the `preview` package of TeX-Live?

Tags: preview, texlive-2016

**Context**:

I am running version 2016.41843 of TeX-Live on my computer (ArchLinux distribution) and am experiencing a defect when using the `preview` package. Unfortunately I cannot find out if this defect is specific to the latest release of TeX-Live or to ArchLinux because I can only verify it with `sharelatex.com` or an Ubuntu 14.04 running TeX-Live 2013. Also it does not seem that there was a change in the `preview` package recently which makes me unsure about what to do now.

**Problem**:

The attached `LaTeX` code used to produce a minimal and tightened page that contains only a box with the text "Node content". Unfortunately it does not anymore. Instead the box is placed in the upper left area of a letter sized canvas.  A second example is showing the same issue with `longtable`.

**Question**:

Can you verify the issue using a most recent TeX-Live distribution? How should I proceed? Which alternatives do I have to work around this issue?

**Example**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={top color=white, bottom color=gray}]
\node{Node content};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{c}
ab
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

**What it should look like:**
[image: A gray filled box that contains "Node content"]

**What it looks like:**
[image]

Comment: Verified. I guess the reason is that in TL2016 tikz etc. pull in graphic.cfg which now leads to a defined page sizes of the default page size.

Comment: Hi @MartinSchröder, thank you for verifying it so fast. I have extended the question to work arounds. Do you know of one I could use instead of `preview`?

Comment: How are you compiling? With pdflatex?

Comment: `LuaLaTeX` because of the `TikZ` `graphdrawing` library.

Comment: Then load (early) \usepackage{luatex85}. In the new luatex `\pdfoutput` is no longer defined and this confuse preview.

Comment: Hello Ulrike, can you please post this an an aswer stating that this is an issue related to `LuaLaTeX`? I'd like to mark this as a solution. I really missed that this could be related to the processor. Thank you very much for pointing this out! I really love the `preview` environment because it's putting each occurrence of a `\PreviewEnvironment` on a separate page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When compiling with lualatex you should load `luatex85`. In the new luatex `\pdfoutput` is no longer defined and this confuses `preview`.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={top color=white, bottom color=gray}]
\node{Node content};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

For this I recommend `standalone`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={top color=white, bottom color=gray}]
\node{Node content};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The grey border is the window background when I took the screenshot. The following is the exact PNG that gets produced when the first line is

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
```

and `pdflatex` is run with the `-shell-escape` option.w

[image]

Comment: Hi @egreg, thank you for answering so fast. Unfortunately I missed yesterday that `standalone` is facing the same issue like `preview` when using `LuaLaTeX`. As I just briefly tested it back then using the `TeXworks` defaults it compiled perfectly with `pdfLaTeX` and did not make me recognize that it's all an `LuaLaTeX` issue.

Comment: @Christoph Add `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` before the `\documentclass` line